# Observable Finally on Subscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

According to [this artcle](http://paqmind.com/posts/rxjs-error-and-completed-events-demystified/), `onComplete` and `onError` function of the `subscribe` are mutually exclusive.

Meaning either `onError` or `onComplete` events will fire up in my `subscribe`.
I have a logic block which needs to be executed whether I receive an error, or I finish my steam of information successfully.

I looked up for something like [`finally` in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), but all I found is [`finally`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md) which needs to be attached to the observable I create.

But I want to to do that logic only when I subscribe, and after the stream has ended, whether successfully or with an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The current "pipable" variant of this operator is called `finalize()` (since RxJS 6). The older and now deprecated "patch" operator was called `finally()` (until RxJS 5.5).

I think `finalize()` operator is actually correct. You say:

> do that logic only when I subscribe, and after the stream has ended

which is not a problem I think. You can have a single `source` and use `finalize()` before subscribing to it if you want. This way you're not required to *always* use `finalize()`:

```
let source = new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.error('error message');
  observer.next(3);
  observer.complete();
}).pipe(
  publish(),
);

source.pipe(
  finalize(() => console.log('Finally callback')),
).subscribe(
  value => console.log('#1 Next:', value),
  error => console.log('#1 Error:', error),
  () => console.log('#1 Complete')
);

source.subscribe(
  value => console.log('#2 Next:', value),
  error => console.log('#2 Error:', error),
  () => console.log('#2 Complete')
);

source.connect();
```

This prints to console:

```
#1 Next: 1
#2 Next: 1
#1 Error: error message
Finally callback
#2 Error: error message
```

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: Interesting that it is kind of the opposite pattern of Promises, in that the `finally()` method is appended first, and the subscription imperatively coerces pass/fail.

Comment: Yeah, that's too bad. One would think that the `finally` block would come last in your code.

Comment: I liked the promise system of Angular JS...As d512 says I expected "finally" to be the last...Don't like this at all...

Comment: As of RXJS 5.5, "finally" is no longer an Observable method. Use the "finalize" operator instead: source.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('Finally callback'))).subscribe(...); https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: the problem with finalize is it waits for a "complete()" call. what if you want a finally on each emission (if observable emission is success do _a_, if it errors, do _b_ instead .. in both cases, do _c_)?

Comment: @robertotomás finalize waits for either complete() or error() (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize)

Answer (score 146):

The only thing which worked for me is this

```
fetchData()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
       //Called when success
     },
    (error) => {
       //Called when error
    }
  ).add(() => {
       //Called when operation is complete (both success and error)
  });
```

Comment: I used this to fetch table data after a delete file subscription, and it worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Do you know if this one also with without having anything in the subscribe method ?, like `.subscribe().add(() => {})` ?

Comment: It doesn't work if you're unsubscribing it before it have the time to complete. I would go for the accepted answer, which do not have this problem

Answer (score 38):

I'm now using RxJS 5.5.7 in an Angular application and using `finalize` operator has a weird behavior for my use case since is fired before success or error callbacks.

Simple example:

```
// Simulate an AJAX callback...
of(null)
  .pipe(
    delay(2000),
    finalize(() => {
      // Do some work after complete...
      console.log('Finalize method executed before "Data available" (or error thrown)');
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('Data available.');
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
  );
```

I have had to use the `add` medhod in the subscription to accomplish what I want. Basically a `finally` callback after the success or error callbacks are done. Like a `try..catch..finally` block or `Promise.finally` method.

Simple example:

```
// Simulate an AJAX callback...
of(null)
  .pipe(
    delay(2000)
  )
  .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('Data available.');
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
  )
  .add(() => {
    // Do some work after complete...
    console.log('At this point the success or error callbacks has been completed.');
  });
```

Comment: The finalize operator must have changed since this answer was posted. Using the code you posted stating the finalize operator is being called prematurely, it works as expected for me.

Comment: @wizloc Yes, there exists a long old thread about unexpected finalize behavior on their issue tracker. Some argued that the (old) behavior was technically correct (if you read the old specification carefully), but in the end the argument that this behavior surprised most users won and it was eventually changed.