# Observables: Complete vs finally vs done

Tags: rxjs, observable

When speaking about Observables (especially rxjs), what is the difference between "finally" and "done" or "complete"?

Answer (score 39):

Finally always happens whenever an observable sequence terminates (including errors); completed only happens when it terminates without errors.

Finally:

> Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence
>   terminates gracefully or exceptionally.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md

OnCompleted:

> An Observable calls this method after it has called `onNext` for the
>   final time, if it has not encountered any errors.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html

"Done" isn't an rx/observables concept. I've just seen it printed in examples of "Complete" / "OnComplete".

Note: when you call `subscribe`, the syntax is usually:

```
observable.subscribe([observer] | [onNext], [onError], [onCompleted]);
// Like this:
observable.subscribe(
    (value) => { ... },
    (error) => { ... },
    () => { console.log('complete!'); }
);
```

or

```
observable.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});
```

Whereas `finally` is handled like this:

```
observable.finally(() => { console.log('finally!'); })
          .subscribe(...) // you can still call subscribe
```

Comment: **Note for rxjs 6+** you can use add as finally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115530/3497671

Answer (score 17):

To be more precise, the `finally()` operator adds a dispose handler. The `complete` notification just calls the complete handler in observers.

What this means in practise:

- When using `finally()` the callback is going to be called in every situation that causes unsubscription. That's when `complete` and `error` notifications are received by observers but also when you manually unsubscribe.

  See demo: https://jsbin.com/dasexol/edit?js,console
- `complete` or `error` handlers are called only when the appropriate notification is received. Only `0 - 1` handlers can be called but never both of them.