# Angular 6 / Rxjs - how to basics: observables success, error, finally

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, finally

I'm building an architecture on latest Angular 6 and coming from AngularJS there's something I can't make peace about: the basic processing of an HTTP request.

So, for the sake of the question, let's say I want an observable. Because it seems to be the future of Angular.

I went from something very elegant, in AngularJS :

```
   service.getAll()
    .then(onSuccess) // I process the data
    .catch(onError) // I do whatever needed to notify anyone about the issue
    .finally(onFinally); // I stop the loading spinner and other stuff
```

Now in Angular 6/RxJS 6, I don't understand why everything is so complicated and look not right.

I could find two ways of doing the same thing than above:

1. The full pipe

   ```
   this.service.getAll()
       .pipe(
           map((data) => this.onSuccess(data)),
           catchError(error => of(this.handleError(error))),
           finalize(() => this.stopLoading())
       )
       .subscribe();
   ```

Since we have to use pipe for the finalize, I might as well use pipe for everything, I think it's better practice to have everything in the same order. But now we have to throw something, called "of" (not very easy to understand) and I don't like that.

2. The half pipe
   So I try another idea, with only the pipe I need (finalize) and I keep the subscribe callbacks.

   ```
   this.service.getAll()
   .pipe(
       finalize(() => this.stopLoading())
   )
   .subscribe(
       (data) => this.onSuccess(data),
       (error) => this.handleError(error)
   );
   ```

But, well. Isn't it a little bit backward? We still have callbacks without actual names, and we finalize before reading the processing and the error. Weird.

So there is something I definitely don't understand. And I can't find anything related to this basic question online. You either have someone who wants "success and finally", or "success and error" but noone wants the 3 of them.
Maybe I'm too old and I don't understand the new best practice about that (if so, please educate me!).

My need is simple:
1. I want to process the data I get from a service
2. I want to get the error in order to display to the user
3. I want to stop the loading spinner I just started before the call, or make another call once the first one is complete success or error (I really want a finally)

How do you handle your basic HTTP call with observable?

(I don't want any `.toPromise`, please, I want to understand how to do with the new stuff)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think there's one key misunderstanding:

> You either have someone who wants "success and finally", or "success and error" but none wants the 3 of them.

This isn't entirely true. Each Observable can send zero or more `next` notifications and one `error` or `complete` notification but never both. For example when making a successful HTTP call you'll have one `next` and one `complete` notification. On error HTTP request you'll have only one `error` notification and that's all. See http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

This means you'll never have an Observable emitting both `error` and `complete`.

And then there's the `finalize` operator. This operator is invoked when disposing the chain (which includes plain unsubscribing as well). In other words it's called **after** both `error` and `complete` notifications.

So the second example you have is correct. I understand it looks weird that you include `finalize` before subscribing but in fact each emissions from the source Observable goes first from top to bottom where it reaches subscribers and there if its `error` or `complete` notification it triggers dispose handlers bottom up (in opposite order) and at this point `finalize` is called. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L150-L152

In your example using `finalize` is the same as adding the dispose handler yourself into a `Subscription` objects.

```
const subscription = this.service.getAll()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => this.onSuccess(data),
    (error) => this.handleError(error)
  );

subscription.add(() => this.stopLoading());
```

Comment: This is very close to what I had in mind. Thank you for the explanation. I just have the word "add" instead of "finally" but since it's in the right reading order, I think this is ok.

        `this.service.getAll().subscribe(success,error).add(finally);`

Comment: @SimonPeyou I'm on the same spot as you, jumping from Promises to Observables is so mindblowing rough due this strange naming conventions. On HTTP requests I prefer to have interceptors to catch errors and let the promises/observables fail with a finally to clean things up.

Comment: Great explaination, although it took me some time to find the description of add(), [Adds a tear down to be called during the unsubscribe() of this Subscription](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html#instance-method-add)

Answer (score 9):

The `subscribe` method of Observable accepts 3 optional functions as parameters

- the first one to process the data which come with the event raised by
  the Observable
- the second one to process any error if it occurs
- the third one to do something on completion of the Observable

So, if I understand correctly, what you want can be achieved with code that looks like this

```
this.service.getAll()
.subscribe(
    data => this.onSuccess(data),
    error => this.handleError(error),
    () => this.onComplete()
);
```

Consider that using Observables for http calls can give benefits when you want to retry (see `retry` operator) on in case you have race conditions (via the use of `switchMap` operator). I think these are the main reasons why Angular team has chosen this approach for the http client.

Generally speaking I think it is worth starting to know how Observables work and some of the most important operators (in addition to the ones above, I think first about `mergeMap`, `filter`, `reduce` - but then there are many others) is important because they can significantly simplify many tasks in asynchronous non blocking environments, such as the Browser (or Node for instance).

Comment: Sadly, and correct me if I'm wrong, the "complete" argument in the `.subscribe` signature is fired when everything went well. It's not fired in case of an error.

I understand the benefits of Observable, I'm not advocating against them. I just want to be sure how to do this basic (and maybe why it is not the basic good practice anymore).

Comment: Yes, you are right, either `complete` or `error` or nothing, for Observables which never complete. I do not understand the sad part though.

Comment: Same comment as above, and I'm starting to think I miss something obvious about it: in my example where do I call the stopLoading then?

Comment: @Picci I think what he wants is finally not completed which is called only after success. What he want is like a closure after either success or failure. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771000/667767 to see the different between completed and finally aka finalize

Answer (score 3):

I think the right way is to use Observable functions: next, err, complete.
Here is an example of how you can trigger the complete function.

Let say we have BehaviorSubject object:

```
let arr = new BehaviorSubject<any>([1,2]);
```

Now lets assume we want to subscribe to it, and if we get the value "finish" we want to complete.

```
let arrSubscription = arr.asObservable().subscribe(
  data => {
      console.log(data)
      if(data === 'finish') {
        arr.complete()
      }
  },
  err => {
      console.log(err)
  },
  () => {
      console.log("Complete function triggered.")
  }
);
arr.next([3,4])
arr.next('finish')
arr.next([5,6])
```

The console log is:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
finish
Complete function triggered.
```

Since we triggered the complete function, the last .next to our BehaviorSubject wont fired, since err and complete function are terminators of the subscription.
This is just an example how u can triggered the complete function, from here you can do what ever you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how this is working with Angular HTTP observable.
If I'm in error, I need to call complete as well then. I might as well call my postCompletion functions there.

Comment: No, error and complete are terminators of the subscription while data is infinite. If you have error, you should handle the error, and its not the same behavior as handle a complete.

Comment: In my example where do I call the stopLoading then?

Comment: if stopLoading is a function that act the same both in error and in complete, than you have to call on both... in error you might wanna do something differently , lets say display a message  to user plus error icon, and in complete you want just stop the spinner. its all depends on your needs.

Comment: So there is no point in finalize, then. In this case, I mean.

Comment: From my knowledge, Finalize is a function that call when error or complete, so its contains both callbacks, but if you wanna handle errors, i dont think its the right choice. its better to split the actions between error and complete. But its your call. Hope you got it right, good luck