# How to return data from subscribe using async/await

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to execute functions below a subscribe, but just when this finish. I have two components, a principal o father component which receives the information from the backend, and the grandchild, which gets the data filtered from the grandfather.

#### Service

In the service, there are functions to share data between components, and a function to process data and split how I need it.

```
sendDataToMap(dataToMap: []) {
    this.send_data.next(dataToMap);
  }

  reciveDataToMap(): Observable<any>{
    return this.send_data.asObservable();
  }

getDataToRenderOnMap(dataToMap){

    dataToMap.forEach((data) => {

      this.routesList.push(data?.mbl_vessels?.path);

      const currentPos: number[] = Object.values(data?.mbl_vessels?.currentPosition);
      this.pointsToFit.push(currentPos);

      const marker: IMarker = {
        transportType: data?.quote?.transportationMode,
        currentPosition: currentPos
      }

      this.markersToRender.push(marker);

    });

    return {
      routesList: this.routesList,
      pointsToFit: this.pointsToFit,
      markersToRender: this.markersToRender
    }

  }
```

#### father component

In the father component, there is the process to filter data which have this property, and send the array.

```
this.elementsToMap = elementsReq.data.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('mbl_vessels'));
this.miniMapService.sendDataToMap(this.elementsToMap);
```

#### grandchild component

Receive the data, process, and use a function to get the data that I need to use for draw the routes and other processes on the map.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.loadMap(MapStyles.COLOR_STYLE);
    this.loadMapControls();

    this.prepareDataToMap();

    //The idea is to execute the functions below once is finished the subscribe process end
    //And return the data out of subscribe


    this.setLineStyle(LinePathColor.TO_COLOR, geoData);
    this.setCustomMarkers();
    this.setMarkerForBounding(shipmentsDataPosition);

    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

prepareDataToMap(){
    this.miniMapService.reciveDataToMap().subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataToMap = data;
      this.dataReturned = this.miniMapService.getDataToRenderOnMap(this.dataToMap);
    });
  }

setLineStyle(colorPath: string, route?) {

    this.mapa.on('load', () => {
      this.mapa.addSource('route', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'properties': {},
          'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': route
          }
        }
      });

      this.mapa.addLayer({
        'id': 'route',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'route',
        'layout': {
          'line-join': 'round',
          'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
          'line-color': colorPath,
          'line-width': 2,
          "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2]
        }
      });
    });

  }
```

[image: cl]

The first console show undefined, the second show the data, but this is because is inside the subscribe.

[image: data]

The data I get is processed once it is received in the grandchild component

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is the expected outcome? What exactly are you trying to achieve, or what is not working as you expect?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Could you review it the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something when the observable ends maybe you can try with the complete method of observables

https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

When the complete value is emited you run those methods
[Observables: Complete vs finally vs done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770999/observables-complete-vs-finally-vs-done)