# How to test code executed in .finally()

Tags: rxjs

The `finally` works as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707379/observable-finally-on-subscribe/40722965).

How do I test code that is run in finally?

```
// code
function doCall(body) {
  isWaitingForRequestToComplete();
  return this.apiService
    .someRequest(body)
    .map(response => transform(response))
    .catch(error => Observable.of('Request failed: ' + error.message))
    .finally(() => {
      requestHasCompleted()
      console.log("Finally");
    });
}

// unit test
it('test observable', () => {
  const testBody = {};
  doCall(testBody).subscribe(() => {
    expect(isWaitingForRequestToComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(apiService.someRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log("Finally should have been executed");
    expect(requestHasCompleted).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Output is:

```
# Finally should have been executed
# Finally
# expect spy requestHasCompleted to have been called
```

So the finally is called after the `subscribe(next)` is executed, which makes sense. Putting the expectation in completed: `subscribe(next, error, completed)`, also doesn't help.

Comment: Docs are very clear that `subscribe` is still required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lol, autocomplete gave me the answer.
On a whim I just put a `.`after the `subscribe()` to see if there is any handler for what happens after a subscription, and got the following suggestions: `.add, .closed, .remove, .unsubscribe`.

`.add(function)    Adds a tear down to be called during the unsubscribe() of this subscription`.

To take the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707379/observable-finally-on-subscribe?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
/// code
  source
    .finally(() => console.log('Finally callback'))
    .subscribe(value => console.log('#1 Next:', value), error => console.log('#1 Error:', error), () => console.log('#1 Complete'))
    .add(() => {
      console.log('Executed after finally is called');
    });

/// output
# ...
# Finally calllback
# Executed after finally is called
```

Although I don't quite understand what triggers the `unsubscribe()` (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html).
I always thought that subscriptions just lie around until they are explicitly unsubscribed from...

Comment: "I always thought that subscriptions just lie around until they are explicitly unsubscribed from..." no it does not. For example take a look to the marble of `of`. It emits what it has to and complete right after the last value.

Comment: @Maxime So unsubscribe happens automatically after the `completed` event... also makes sense. Would be great to have some docs somewhere that explains the observable lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `it(...)` for tests I suppose you're using `jasmine` or `mocha` where you can use an optional argument `done` to test asynchronous functions.

```
it('test observable', done => {
  this.apiService
    .someRequest(...)
    .map(...)
    .finally(done)
    .subscribe();
})
```

Notice I used `.finally(done)` to tell the test environment when this method properly ends. If I didn't call `done()` the test would fail on timeout.

Comment: I didn't have an issue with the test failing due to timeout, but with where to put the `expect()` query, so that the code in `finally()` has already been executed. `done` solves a problem I didn't have.

Comment: That's the point. You don't need to use `expect` to check whether `finally()` was executed or not. That's what `done` is for. Moreover you can't use `expect` if the Observable chain is asynchronous (for example if you used the `delay` operator).