# RxJs difference between complete and unsubscribe in Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

After complete event will unsubscribe Observable or not or any other difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771350/rxjs-subscriber-unsubscribe-vs-complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJS Subscriber unsubscribe vs. complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771350/rxjs-subscriber-unsubscribe-vs-complete)

Answer (score 49):

You complete an `Observable`, and unsubscribe a `Subscription`. These are two different methods on two different objects. You subscribe to an observable which returns a `Subscription` object.

If you want to stop listening to emits from the `Observable` you call `subscription.unsubscribe()`.

If you want an `Observable` to be done with his task, you call `observable.complete()`. (this only exists on `Subject` and those who extend `Subject`). The complete method in itself will also unsubscribe any possible subscriptions.

> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.

Comment: where did you read about "The complete method in itself will also unsubscribe any possible subscriptions."? Does that mean that having 2 subscriptions and if we complete the `Observable` without unsubscribing the 2 `Subscription`s will handle the `unsubscribe()` method for us? In other words, is the `unsubscribe()` optional if we `complete()` the Observable?

Comment: @DiegoOsornio that is true, the `unsubscribe` is optional, you can read about it in the reactivex contract [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html). I'll update my answer with a quote from this doc

Comment: best explaination

Comment: _"When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way."_ [Subscribing and Unsubscribing](https://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)

Answer (score 12):

If you complete an `Observable`, it will call `complete()` method then the teardown logic and `unsubscribe()`.
Calling `unsubscribe()` itself does not call complete method.
Angular async pipe is an example of calling `unsubscribe`. Therefore, if you have complete method and using async pipe, it will not be called.