# Rxjs takeUntil in-depth

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have read about the concept of using `takeUntil` operator to manage `unsubscribe` in `ngDestroy`.

I would like to go a bit further and understand step by step the operator. It is my first step inside rxjs before going further (others operators).

To start I read line by line [the source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeUntil.ts)
and to help me this one too [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198240/rxjs-difference-between-complete-and-unsubscribe-in-observable)

- I don't see any unsubscribe, except inside the `createOperatorSubscriber` = the notifier Observable
- I don't see the link between when the notifier complete and the source Observable.
- is it the subscriber.complete which triggers the unsubscribe of the source Observable ? (the other SO question talk about that but I'm missing a piece)
- the source Observable is lifted (if it's a Subject we create an AnonymousSubject) but I can't see its role.

Is someone can go deep and explains to me via a code review the inner mechanisms of `takeUntil` ?

**Update:** Thanks @drenai. I split the post in two.

Below, I added more explanation of my journey. Welcome to my brain :)
I got a simple Angular usecase :

- I have a service containing a BehaviorSubject monitoring a combobox and emiting the new value
- inside a component `ngOnInit` hook I subscribe to the previous subject
- and when I receive a new value I fetch some data over http.
- my first try was using a `switchMap` to pipe the operations
- and then I was wondering about the unsubscription

  1. if I store the resulting `Subscription' object is it enough to avoid a memory leak (does it unsubscrive from the first Observable)
  2. if I just don't do anything, is it the http call that manage the subscription ?
  3. do I need to add takeUntil
- this was the moment where my need to understand the implementation scratches me
- I'm hoping that understanding the "takeUntil" operator will permit me to have a better view of the others pipeable operators.

Bonus :

- if two components on the same page have subscribed to the BehaviorSubject. Is the first `takeUntil` destroy operation unsubscribe all subscribers ? I don't really imagine that but asking that is another way to see that I'm missing another piece :)

Comment: @Drenai did you delete your answer or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it the subscriber.complete which triggers the unsubscribe of the source Observable ?

Yes. The subscriber will be automatically unsubscribed when its [complete](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L101) is triggered (also see `_complete` in that link)

> if I just don't do anything, is it the http call that manages the subscription ?

The `HttpClient` call will eventually complete and the subscriber will be unsubscribed e.g. after a 500ms API call. But.... if you be navigate away from the page while the API call is in-flight you probably want to cancel the HttpClient call and unsubscribe - that's where the `takeUntil` would come in

> Is the first takeUntil destroy operation unsubscribing all subscribers ?

Nope. Each subscription's `takeUntil` would just manage that particular subscription to the `BehaviorSubject`.

**Note:** this unsubscribe/cancel feature is not something one would be familiar with if coming from Promise notification system, as [there's no native way to cancel a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478751/cancel-a-vanilla-ecmascript-6-promise-chain?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)