# Should I unsubscribe after a complete?

Tags: rxjs

I have a quick question about observable.

I have the following observable:

```
  getElevation(pos: Cartographic): Observable<Cartographic> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const promise = Cesium.sampleTerrain(this.terrainProvider, 11, Cesium.Cartographic(pos.longitude, pos.latitude))
      Cesium.when(promise, (updatedPositions) => {
        observer.next(updatedPositions);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```

In a component I have:

```
this.service.getElevation(value).subscribe((e) => {});
```

My question is, this is a one shoot observable, so I complete just after, is the complete automatically close the subscription? or, do I also have to do this:

```
const sub = this.service.getElevation(value).subscribe((e) => {sub.unsubscribe();});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771350/rxjs-subscriber-unsubscribe-vs-complete

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not unsubscribe in a subscription, it the observable emits instantly then sub is undefined.

If you want a self unsubscribing observable you can use takeUntil

```
finalise = new Subject();
this.service.getElevation(value).pipe(takeUntil(finalise)).subscribe((e) => { 
  finalise.next();
  finalise.complete();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be equivalent to `this.service.getElevation(value).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((e) => {});`

Comment: The difference is that you can control when finalise is called, usually in ngOnDestroy. The problem with take 1 is that you cannot be guaranteed that the observable has emitted and might fire after you expect. In this circumstance it basically is equivalent, but the call to finalise should usually be made in a deconstructor.

Answer (score 12):

**In your case you don't need to unsubscribe.**

All Observers will automatically be unsubscribed when you call `complete`. That said, you may want to implement your consuming (component) code do handle the possibility that the implementation of the service may change in the future.

You could do this by using the `take` operator which will unsubscribe after the first value is emitted:

```
this.service.getElevation(value).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((e) => {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Brief note:

- Try to control the subscription with **operators** such as `takeUntil`.
- You don’t need to unsubscribe yourself if the sender(Subject) completes.
- For your case, since the sender returned by `getElevation` function completes itself after emitting a value one time, you don’t need to either use any operator or unsubscribe yourself to unsubscribe it.

All you have to do: `this.service.getElevation(value).subscribe((v) => // do what you want);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you observable calls `observer.complete()` and you are certain that it will complete in case of success or failure then the answer is no, there's no need to unsubscribe. It completes on it's own, which means it unsubscribes all subscribers automatically.

If you are not sure that that third party library you are using will proceed to the `observer.complete()` line, then you must unsubscribe in case of failure.